# how to use OCaml's Cohttp library to make a HTTPS request

Tags: ssl, https, ocaml, ocaml-dune

How can I use the [Cohttp](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp) library to `GET` a URL over HTTPS?

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let url = "https://google.com"

let do_request =
  Client.get (Uri.of_string url) >>= fun (resp, body) ->
  body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string

let run () =
  let body = Lwt_main.run do_request in
  print_endline ("Received body\n" ^ body)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: exception (Failure "Ssl not available")
```

How can I *enable SSL when using Cohttp*?

Also, as a bonus question, how should I have been able to figure this out without resorting to asking here?  Is there some sort of Cohttp documentation I have missed?

---

@antron asked the question below, "Do you have the `ssl` library installed?"

I do have the `ssl` library installed:

```
$ opam list ssl
# Available packages for 4.05.0:
ssl  0.5.3  Bindings for OpenSSL
```

However, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but my `cohttp` package doesn't show a `depends` on `ssl`:

```
$ opam info --field depends cohttp
base-bytes & jbuilder >= 1.0+beta10 & re & uri >= 1.9.0 & fieldslib & sexplib & ppx_fields_conv >= v0.9.0 & ppx_sexp_conv >= v0.9.0 & stringext & base64 >= 2.0.0 & magic-mime & fmt & logs & jsonm
```

---

I'm running on Arch Linux with OCaml version 4.05.0, installed through `opam switch`.

Just in case, here is the `jbuild` file I'm using:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executables
((names (main))
  (libraries (cohttp cohttp-lwt-unix core lwt))))

(install
((section bin)
  (files ((main.exe as my_example_prog)))))
```

I am running `jbuilder` like the following. I get no errors when compiling:

```
$ jbuilder build @install
```

I am running the `my_example_prog` executable like the following:

```
$ _build/install/default/bin/my_example_prog
Fatal error: exception (Failure "Ssl not available")
```

You can find the full OCaml project I'm using [here](https://github.com/cdepillabout/examples/tree/76028831687a53652fd2d0576f367333a02168b8/code/guided-tour/weather_api).

Comment: Have you tried also installing the `ssl` package from OPAM?

Comment: @antron I believe I already have the `ssl` package installed.  I updated the question showing this.

Comment: Interesting. A lot of these packages have been reorganized recently. `cohttp-lwt-unix` depends on `conduit-lwt-unix`, which depends (optionally) on `ssl` and `lwt`. I suggest trying to install `lwt_ssl`, then maybe `opam reinstall conduit-lwt-unix` to get it to reconfigure itself. If that doesn't work, PUNISHED BAYGE from Discord suggests pinning the packages to their development versions, e.g. `opam pin add conduit-lwt-unix --dev-repo`, etc.

Comment: FYI I was just able to get Cohttp with SSL working this way, without resorting to pins.

Comment: Also, this is a bug in the packaging of `conduit-lwt-unix`, so no, there is no documentation to find for this. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-conduit/issues/237) on it.

Comment: @antron Installing `lwt_ssl` and then reinstalling `conduit-lwt-unix` fixed my problem.  Thanks!  Also, thanks for creating the issue on ocaml-conduit.

Comment: This also worked for me. Thank's @antron!